# MSP430 RTC Calibration issue

Tags: msp430, iar

I am using MSP430F5418 with IAR EW 5.10.

I am trying to output the  RTCCLK signal from MSP's 29th pin with a frequency of 1Hz.

When I output the signal it is coming through the port.

But after I re-writing the RTC time, the signal stopped.

I tried to re-enable it, but it didn't worked.

Can anybody tell me what the reason is??

I am using the Work-around code provided by TI for setting RTC time.

My RTC configuration is:

```
RTCCTL01 |= RTCHOLD; 
RTCCTL01 |= RTCMODE + RTCTEV_0 + RTCRDYIE + RTCTEVIE; 
P2DIR |= BIT4; P2SEL |= BIT4; 
RTCCTL23 = RTCCALF1 | RTCCAL0;
RTCCTL01 &= ~(RTCHOLD);
```

Comment: You descriibe two phases in your program, your code shows only one part. Do you want to show what exactly you do when initializing and when re-writing the RTC time?

Comment: I am sorry. The given portion is for initialization. Re-writing is just a function call which modifies the RTCMIN and RTCHOUR registers.

Comment: Today I changed the time in each 10 second instead of one second.
so the signal is coming. Anybody have any Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTC Calibration depends on the output of Pre-scalar timer